# write label value in StreamWriter aspx.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

i have some labels in my webform1.aspx,I keep these label values in session,and i write it in text file through StreamWriter.Now when i navigate on another page and when i came back here label values are exist, but won't write in text file.I cannot understand what is the problem. Here is my code:

```
      StreamWriter writer1 = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Room\bar1.doc",
         false, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));



            using (writer1)
            {
                 if (Label38.Text == "0")
                    {


                        writer1.WriteLine(Label7.Text + Konvert(str) +  Label5.Text + Label4.Text );

                    }
              else if (Label38.Text != null)
                    {
                 writer1.WriteLine( Label7.Text + Konvert(str)  + Label38.Text +Label4.Text );

                    }
             }

       protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

            Session["Minus"] = Label38.Text;
      }
```

Comment: Please take more time to fix the indentation in your code. It's *really* hard to read at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet fix it, please look it now

Comment: @Oscar if you know, help here and write better solution!

Comment: It still looks pretty broken to me, with loads of extra vertical whitespace for no reason, too. "But won't write in text file" doesn't really give us much information, either. If you use the debugger, what values do you see for the labels? What is `writer`? (You've declared `writer1` but not used it, but you haven't declared `writer`...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I keep label values in session, when i navigate on another page, and came back on webform1 where is my labels,try to write lables in text file, but text file is EMPTY without values. But when i NOT navigate on another pages, label values are written in text file.SO the problem is navigating throug pages

Comment: That doesn't answer most of the questions I asked - importantly, it doesn't tell us what you've seen when debugging. It may well just be a session issue, in which case what you do with the values is really just a symptom and the question should be around keeping a session open. It's hard to tell without more information though.

Answer (score 0):

1: Are you sure that your entering in your if statement ?

2: You're Writing with Writer instead of Writer1 is this OK ?

3: Why do you need 2 SteamWriter since you seem to use only one of them.

Comment: I've edited code, see it,main problem is navigation through pages

Comment: it looks like your still using  "writer.WriteLine..." and not "writer1.WriteLine..."
and did you try with  ' if(Session["Minus"] == ' instead of 'if(Label38.Text =='